# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'vrfCoordinatorV2')

Tags: web3js, hardhat, hardhat-deploy, vrf

Here Is my 01-Deploy-raffle.js Code

```
 const { network } = require("hardhat");
const { ethers } = require("hardhat");
const {
  networkConfig,
  developmentChains,
  VERIFICATION_BLOCK_CONFIRMATIONS,
} = require("../helper-hardhat-config");
const { verify } = require("../utils/verify");

const FUND_AMOUNT = ethers.parseEther("1"); // 1 Ether, or 1e18 (10^18) Wei

module.exports = async ({ getNamedAccounts, deployments }) => {
  const { deploy, log } = deployments;
  const { deployer } = await getNamedAccounts();
  const chainId = network.config.chainId;
  let vrfCoordinatorV2Address, subscriptionId, vrfCoordinatorV2Mock;

  if (chainId == 31337) {
    // create VRFV2 Subscription
    vrfCoordinatorV2Mock = await ethers.getContract("VRFCoordinatorV2Mock");
    vrfCoordinatorV2Address = vrfCoordinatorV2Mock.address;
    const transactionResponse = await vrfCoordinatorV2Mock.createSubscription();
    const transactionReceipt = await transactionResponse.wait();
    subscriptionId = transactionReceipt.events[0].args.subId;
    // Fund the subscription
    // Our mock makes it so we don't actually have to worry about sending fund
    await vrfCoordinatorV2Mock.fundSubscription(subscriptionId, FUND_AMOUNT);
  } else {
    vrfCoordinatorV2Address = networkConfig[chainId]["vrfCoordinatorV2"];
    subscriptionId = networkConfig[chainId]["subscriptionId"];
  }
  const waitBlockConfirmations = developmentChains.includes(network.name)
    ? 1
    : VERIFICATION_BLOCK_CONFIRMATIONS;

  log("----------------------------------------------------");
  const arguments = [
    vrfCoordinatorV2Address,
    subscriptionId,
    networkConfig[chainId]["gasLane"],
    networkConfig[chainId]["keepersUpdateInterval"],
    networkConfig[chainId]["raffleEntranceFee"],
    networkConfig[chainId]["callbackGasLimit"],
  ];
  const raffle = await deploy("Raffle", {
    from: deployer,
    args: arguments,
    log: true,
    waitConfirmations: waitBlockConfirmations,
  });

  // Ensure the Raffle contract is a valid consumer of the VRFCoordinatorV2Mock contract.
  if (developmentChains.includes(network.name)) {
    const vrfCoordinatorV2Mock = await ethers.getContract(
      "VRFCoordinatorV2Mock"
    );
    await vrfCoordinatorV2Mock.addConsumer(subscriptionId, raffle.address);
  }

  // Verify the deployment
  if (
    !developmentChains.includes(network.name) &&
    process.env.ETHERSCAN_API_KEY
  ) {
    log("Verifying...");
    await verify(raffle.address, arguments);
  }

  log("Enter lottery with command:");
  const networkName = network.name == "hardhat" ? "localhost" : network.name;
  log(`yarn hardhat run scripts/enterRaffle.js --network ${networkName}`);
  log("----------------------------------------------------");
};

module.exports.tags = ["all", "raffle"];
```

And Here is my helper-hardhat-config.js

```
const { ethers } = require("hardhat");
const networkConfig = {
  default: {
    name: "hardhat",
    keepersUpdateInterval: "30",
  },
  31337: {
    name: "localhost",
    subscriptionId: "588",
    gasLane:
      "0x474e34a077df58807dbe9c96d3c009b23b3c6d0cce433e59bbf5b34f823bc56c", // 30 gwei
    keepersUpdateInterval: "30",
    raffleEntranceFee: ethers.parseEther("0.01"), // 0.01 ETH
    callbackGasLimit: "500000", // 500,000 gas
  },
  11155111: {
    name: "sepolia",
    subscriptionId: "6926",
    gasLane:
      "0x474e34a077df58807dbe9c96d3c009b23b3c6d0cce433e59bbf5b34f823bc56c", // 30 gwei
    keepersUpdateInterval: "30",
    raffleEntranceFee: ethers.parseEther("0.01"), // 0.01 ETH
    callbackGasLimit: "500000", // 500,000 gas
    vrfCoordinatorV2: "0x8103B0A8A00be2DDC778e6e7eaa21791Cd364625",
  },
};

const developmentChains = ["hardhat", "localhost"];
const VERIFICATION_BLOCK_CONFIRMATIONS = 6;
const frontEndContractsFile =
  "../nextjs-smartcontract-lottery-fcc/constants/contractAddresses.json";
const frontEndAbiFile =
  "../nextjs-smartcontract-lottery-fcc/constants/abi.json";

module.exports = {
  networkConfig,
  developmentChains,
  VERIFICATION_BLOCK_CONFIRMATIONS,
  frontEndContractsFile,
  frontEndAbiFile,
};
```

And Am getting this error

```
Error: ERROR processing /home/apex/Web3/Lottery Web3/deploy/01-deploy-raffle.js:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'vrfCoordinatorV2')
    at Object.module.exports [as func] (/home/apex/Web3/Lottery Web3/deploy/01-deploy-raffle.js:29:53)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at DeploymentsManager.executeDeployScripts (/home/apex/Web3/Lottery Web3/node_modules/hardhat-deploy/src/DeploymentsManager.ts:1211:22)
    at DeploymentsManager.runDeploy (/home/apex/Web3/Lottery Web3/node_modules/hardhat-deploy/src/DeploymentsManager.ts:1060:5)
    at SimpleTaskDefinition.action (/home/apex/Web3/Lottery Web3/node_modules/hardhat-deploy/src/index.ts:450:5)
    at Environment._runTaskDefinition (/home/apex/Web3/Lottery Web3/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/core/runtime-environment.ts:358:14)
    at Environment.run (/home/apex/Web3/Lottery Web3/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/core/runtime-environment.ts:191:14)
    at SimpleTaskDefinition.action (/home/apex/Web3/Lottery Web3/node_modules/hardhat-deploy/src/index.ts:601:32)
    at Environment._runTaskDefinition (/home/apex/Web3/Lottery Web3/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/core/runtime-environment.ts:358:14)
    at Environment.run (/home/apex/Web3/Lottery Web3/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/core/runtime-environment.ts:191:14)
    at DeploymentsManager.executeDeployScripts (/home/apex/Web3/Lottery Web3/node_modules/hardhat-deploy/src/DeploymentsManager.ts:1214:19)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at DeploymentsManager.runDeploy (/home/apex/Web3/Lottery Web3/node_modules/hardhat-deploy/src/DeploymentsManager.ts:1060:5)
    at SimpleTaskDefinition.action (/home/apex/Web3/Lottery Web3/node_modules/hardhat-deploy/src/index.ts:450:5)
    at Environment._runTaskDefinition (/home/apex/Web3/Lottery Web3/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/core/runtime-environment.ts:358:14)
    at Environment.run (/home/apex/Web3/Lottery Web3/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/core/runtime-environment.ts:191:14)
    at SimpleTaskDefinition.action (/home/apex/Web3/Lottery Web3/node_modules/hardhat-deploy/src/index.ts:601:32)
    at Environment._runTaskDefinition (/home/apex/Web3/Lottery Web3/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/core/runtime-environment.ts:358:14)
    at Environment.run (/home/apex/Web3/Lottery Web3/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/core/runtime-environment.ts:191:14)
    at SimpleTaskDefinition.action (/home/apex/Web3/Lottery Web3/node_modules/hardhat-deploy/src/index.ts:690:5)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

Idk A lot about web3 But if someone can solve this , your welcome

Comment: Its was a silly error I just corrected my Hardhat.config.js file the chainId was missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems fine. The error appears from this line of code

```
vrfCoordinatorV2Address = networkConfig[chainId]["vrfCoordinatorV2"];
```

I think you may set the wrong chain_id in `network.config` (`const chainId = network.config.chainId`). Thus, `networkConfig[chainId]` will be undefined => `networkConfig[chainId]["vrfCoordinatorV2"]` will return error as shown in your console.

Hope it helps you and it would be better to upload your networkConfig also.

Comment: So there was a problem with my haredhat.config.js File the chain ID where missing, thanks :)